# Clojure: how to evaluate a quoted form in the local scope?

Tags: clojure

I want to define a macro that randomly chooses one of the given expressions and evaluates it. For example,

```
(equal-chance
  (println "1")
  (println "2"))
```

should print "1" half the time and "2" the other half.

I tried using,

```
(defmacro equal-chance
  [& exprs]
    `(rand-nth '~exprs))
```

but this returns one of the quoted forms, rather than evaluating it (i.e. it would return `(println "1")` rather than actually printing "1"). I cannot use `eval` because it does not preserve the bindings. For example,

```
(let [x 10] (eval '(println x)))
```

complains that it is unable to resolve symbol x.

Is there a way to evaluate a quoted form in the local scope? Or maybe there is a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't evaluate a run-time value in a lexical environment that only exists at compile time.  The solution is to use `fn` instead of `quote` and a function call instead of `eval`:

```
(defmacro equal-chance [& exprs]
  `((rand-nth [~@(map (fn [e] `(fn [] ~e)) exprs)])))
```

The way this works is by expanding `(equal-chance e1 e2 ...)` into `((rand-nth [(fn [] e1) (fn [] e2) ...]))`.

Comment: this works great! never would have figured this out on my own, thanks

Comment: I prefer to use delay/force rather than fn/call for this: `(force (rand-nth [~@(map (partial list \`delay) exprs)]))`

Answer (score 1):

Just don't quote the call to `rand-nth` or the expressions. This will do what you want:

```
(defmacro equal-chance
  [& exprs]
    (rand-nth exprs))
```

Comment: This doesn't work for all cases. `(dotimes [i 10] (equal-chance 1 2 3))` will return one of those numbers 10 times.